# Questions about the field scientific computing

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, applications, computational-mathematics

I have heard about the field of Applied and Computational Mathematics, Scientific Computing and want to get some information. Is this a combination of computer science and mathematics? What subjects are related with this field?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that most of what you want to know about lies within the domain of computational mathematics.

Indeed, there is an intersection between computational mathematics and computer science; certainly in the context of [computer algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm).

An essential aspect of computational mathematics is the study of [numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) which includes (but is not limited to) [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), [numerical quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration), and [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), to name a few of the areas a course on the topic of computational mathematics might cover.

I think that should be enough information to give you a general idea of the scope of the field.  You may get a more useful answer if you explained why exactly you're asking this question in the first place.

Comment: I am asking because I'm  interested in pursuing a master's degree maybe in this field... So what scientific interests should one have to choose for this field? Should one like especially the subjects you mentioned(numerical methods, linear programming, ...)?

Comment: I study SC and it's basically numerical methods. So you should be interested in algorithms in general, and algorithms to solve PDEs, algorithms to interpolate functions, algorithms for approximation, maybe Fourier- and Functional Analysis. So if you love algorithms, computer science AND math - Scientifc Computing would be the best choice :)

Comment: Ahaa!!! Ok!!! That sounds great! Actually I have a dilemma.. I am between pursuing a master's degree in scientific computing or in theoretical computer science(Algorithmic & Systems Analysis). Which of them would you suggest me? What career opportunities are there in each case?

Comment: I know what you're going through. I can never decide between computational science and theoretical computer science. But since PDEs are very popular at the moment, I would suggest scientific computing for career opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Scientific computing deals with solving mathematical/scientific problems using computers. 
Typically, those problems have large scale, so solving them without computers is impractical, so computational mathematics deals with the challenges arise when using computers. The algorithm should be practical. Here are examples for typical challenges:

1) Efficiency - the algorithm should run in a reasonable time.

2) Computer memory limitation. How to fit a large scale problem into the memory?

3) Utilizing computer architecture - Parallel, etc.

4) Accuracy/Numerical stability - Does our solution is accurate and numerically stable? Both from "pure" mathematical perspective and by computer considerations (floating point precision, etc.)

Though the field may sound a little bit "too practical", there are often proofs for bounding condition numbers, error, convergence rate, etc. So it is strictly mathematical.

As more concrete examples for research in mathematics: numerical linear algebra, optimization, Lp minimization and sparse representations.

In engineering: computer vision, Big data, recommendation systems, bioinformatics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks for the information! Actually I have a dilemma.. I am between pursuing a master's degree in scientific computing or in theoretical computer science(Algorithmic & Systems Analysis). Which of them would you suggest me? What career opportunities are there in each case?

Comment: Well, I am not an expert for TCS, but from what I saw there is a certain overlap between the subjects. What I don't like about TCS is that sometimes you can see in academic research things like "Solving XYZ in linear time" and then you see that it gives you a solution to a given precision, say $\epsilon$ and then you see that the complexity can be something like $\mathcal{O}(n/\epsilon^{10})$. So yeah, it's linear but it's not practical. I prefer things that work... Check journals of both classes. I'll recommend some in the next comment.

Comment: Good scientific computing journals are "SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing" and "Applied and Computational Harmonic Analysis" (which is actually very wide). For theoretical computer science check out FOCS and STOCS.

Comment: Ahaa!! Ok... I will have a look at these journals!!! One more question...Does this field of theoretical computer science have a relation with maths? Is the undergraduate program in applied maths a good basis for a ms in both SC and TCS ?

Comment: Definitely good for SC. I think it's also very good for TCS as well.